# Make activity scale to be the same on all devices? - Android

Tags: android, xml

Can what is described in the title be done? I mean the whole activity just scales up or down to take up the same percentage of the device screen, so buttons and everything else, all views, all free space, margins, grow on a big screen. Is this what "dp" is? So setting all measurements in dp where possible would do this?

Thanks.

Comment: @VamsiPavanMahesh It says on the website provided by Carlos that xlarge screens are at least 960dp x 720dp large screens are at least 640dp x 480dp normal screens are at least 470dp x 320dp small screens are at least 426dp x 320dp This means I cannot just use dp and it will take the same percentage. Correct? Is There a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dp` is the unit you have to use in your dimensions, so everything scales depending on the density of the device. 
But probably you also need to take care of the actual physical size of the screen, the with/height ratio, etc...

You better read this document

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

until everything is quite familiar to you

Comment: Thanks!

xlarge screens are at least 960dp x 720dp
large screens are at least 640dp x 480dp
normal screens are at least 470dp x 320dp
small screens are at least 426dp x 320dp

This means I cannot just use dp and it will take the same percentage. Correct? Is There a way?